# How to add a trailing slash on URL

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like all URLs on my site to have a trailing slash on the URL. I created a simple extension for the URLHelper in Zend. Right now it changes all the word separators to hyphens (-). Adding the functionality to append a trailing slash would be great. The commented out line (hack) didn't work. The slash ended up being url-encoded.

I know this has to be an easy fix and right in front of my face, but it's escaping me. :\

```
    class Ace_Helpers_Url extends Zend_View_Helper_Url
{

   /**
    * Generates an url given the name of a route.
    *
    * @access public
    *
    * @param  array $urlOptions Options passed to the assemble method of the Route object.
    * @param  mixed $name The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route
    * @param  bool $reset Whether or not to reset the route defaults with those provided
    * @return string Url for the link href attribute.
    */
   public function url(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = false)
   {
      if (is_array($urlOptions)) {
         foreach ($urlOptions as $index => $option) {
            $urlOptions[$index] = trim(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $option)));
            #$urlOptions[$index] .= '/'; #Add trailing slash for continuity
         }
      }
      $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
      return $router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode);
   }
}
```

Comment: maybe $router->assemble is stripping it. you might have to override a function somewhere

Comment: $router->assemble isn't necessarily stripping it, but it's encoding the trailing slash (adds a %20 or something like that to the end of the url). I thought setting $encode = false would stop that, but I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is based on [this discussion](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-View-Helper-Url-add-slash-td652116.html).

**application/view/helpers/Url2.php**

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Url2 extends Zend_View_Helper_Url
{
    /**
     * Keeps Url()'s original params and their default values, so we don't have to
     * learn yet another method.
     */
    public function url2(array $urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
    {
        return parent::url($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode) . '/';
    }
}
```

**in some controller**

```
echo $this->view->url2(array('controller' => 'index'));
```

**or some view**

```
echo $this->url2(array('controller' => 'index'));
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing earlier. I just needed to be pushed . It was so easy I refused to believe it would work! :P

Answer (score 3):

Appending it manually isn't really that hard:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array(
        'controller' => 'index'
    )).'/'; ?>
```

If you want to avoid url encoding, check out the fourth parametre to the url helper: `encode`. Set it to false and it will not url-encode your input, so you can do something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array(
        'alias' => 'blog/2011/09/example-blog-entry'
    ),'alias',true,false); ?>
```

Comment: I figured it would be simple to do it like that. I thought there might be a global way to handle this so I don't have to append in the actual echo statement and instead append it in the helper. This will do.